# manipulating email address with a sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, string, stored-procedures

I'm trying to figure out how to best manipulate an email adress within this (part of) stored procedure.

```
IF(@LoginName IS NULL OR @LoginName = '')
BEGIN
    set @LoginName = @Email
END
```

What is happening: a user is saved but If the email already exist the email address receives a number at the end of it. for example: test@email.com12

once this email is written to the database this stored procedure saves the email as the login name. however I want the login name to be just "test@email.com" without the "12" at the end of it. What would the best way to do this be?

Thanks for any help, my sql skills are not very good.

Here is the javascript that alters the email address and writes it to the database

```
function userEdit()
{
    if (typeof userEdit.counter == 'undefined')
    {
        userEdit.counter = 0;
    }
    userEdit.counter++;
    var change = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    var email = change + "" +userEdit.counter;  

    var telephone = document.getElementById("txtTelephone").value;
    var mobile = document.getElementById("txtMobile").value;
    var loginUser = document.getElementById("chkLogin").checked;
    var password = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
    var confirmpassword = document.getElementById("txtConfirmPassword").value;

    card.user.update(wizard.stateInfo.activeUserID, wizard.stateInfo.activeUser, email, telephone, mobile, loginUser, password);
}
```

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: Can you provide more information please. It's hard to give an answer without the backend process. Why is it providing a number in the end? Are you using the e-mail address as a key?

Comment: the email is an ID which is also used to login. But one user can have more than one email... to differenaite the emails the numbers are added at the end. Each email also has a unique ID. The emails are still being stored in the database but the loginName needs to be unique (the original email) I'm using MS SQL Enterprise

Comment: I have added the email altering process in the OP

Answer (score 2):

The best practice here is to keep a record of both the modified and unmodified email addresses, in two different variables.  Then you don't need to "undo" the changes, you just pick the variable that is suitable to your needs at that time.